# Excel VBA: How do I change font size and alignment inside text boxes

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I have created a grid of text boxes, but I cannot figure out a method to change the font size and alignment (centralise vertically and horizonatally) of the text inside a named textbox.

```
Sub addtxtbx()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim cindx as long, rindx as long
For i = 1 To 145
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
            100 + cindx, 100 + rindx, 50, 50)
    cindx = (i - Int((i - 1) / 4) * 4 - 1) * 50 + Int((i - 1) / 48) * 200
    rindx = (Int((i - 1) / 4) - Int((i - 1) / 48) * 12) * 50
    With shp
        .Name = "TxtBx" & (i - 1)
         .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(204, 102, 255)
    End With
Next i

With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TxtBx11")).TextFrame2.TextRange
    .Characters.Text = "R"
End With
End Sub
```

Also, I have been scratching my head with the For Next loop's i counter. I used it to rename the text boxes and found that despite using i = 1 to 144, TxtBx144 is not the last box, but the second last, TxtBx2 is the first. So, I tried to get around it by using 1 to 145 and name the box using (i-1) serial which is a bit of a cop out. What did I do wrong that I am failing to see?

Comment: You have 144 text boxes on a *worksheet*? Why not just use cells for input instead?

Comment: @mat'smug, I actually have cells currently and I need to copy these cells as a picture, paste the picture into a chartobject and save the chartobject as a png. Unfortunately, after so many runs, I keep having to increase the sleep time (on David Zemens' recommendation) to overcome runtime error. Eventually, it would reach a point that no amount of sleep would do it and I have to not only shut down Excel, but reboot the PC to get it working again. Hoping to get around it by using text boxes. I could use one box and adjust the letter spacing... just experimenting for now.

Comment: You're setting the `.Name` to "TxtBx" concatenated with `i - 1`, so `i - 1` goes from 0 to 144 if `i` can be 1 to 145. Not sure what part of that is unclear.

Comment: Perhaps you are making the first textbox, but it is not visible in the sheet....it's in a hidden row or something.  It works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is this:

```
 shp.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
```

where 20 is whatever size you want.

I don't know why your text boxes were getting numbered incorrectly, but your code as written is actually giving me 0-143, not 1-144 so I suspect there is either some code changing i that you haven't put into the question or something else is going on.

Also, the easiest way to figure out how to code stuff like this, is to record a macro, do whatever it is you are trying to accomplish, stop the macro, and then look at the code.

Comment: `.Name = "TxtBx" & (i - 1)` makes it pretty clear why it goes from 0 to 143 IMO. ...or did I miss something?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I agree, but the OP is stating that for them it is actually being 1 to 144 with `i - 1`.

Comment: Thanks @OpiesDad. I tried using macro recorder, but because it had "With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 1).Font" and I wasn't sure about the characters(1,1) part, played with it unsuccessfully

Comment: @OpiesDad, I started with i = 1 to 144, and .Name = "TxtBx" & i. I see what I have done now finally, the second box is overlaying the first box. Very stupid mistake!

Comment: Set shp  should appear below cindx =  and rindx =   lines.